# Trouble using private variables with friend functions

Tags: c++

I have an .h file

```
  #ifndef flashdrive_2_0_h
#define flashdrive_2_0_h

namespace cs52 {

    class FlashDrive {

    public:

        FlashDrive( );
        FlashDrive( int capacity, int used, bool pluggedIn );

        void plugIn( );
        void pullOut( );
        void writeData( int amount );
        void eraseData( int amount );
        void formatDrive( );

        int getCapacity( );
        void setCapacity( int amount );

        int getUsed( );
        void setUsed( int amount );

        bool isPluggedIn( );


        friend FlashDrive operator+(const FlashDrive& flsh1, const FlashDrive& flsh2);


    private:

        int my_StorageCapacity;
        int my_StorageUsed;
        bool my_IsPluggedIn;


    };

}

#endif /* flashdrive_2_0_h */
```

Also a .cpp file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "flashdrive_2_0.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cs52;
using namespace std;


cs52::FlashDrive::FlashDrive() {

    int my_StorageCapacity = 0;
    int my_StorageUsed = 0;
    bool my_IsPluggedIn = false;

}

cs52::FlashDrive::FlashDrive( int capacity, int used, bool pluggedIn ){

    int my_StorageCapacity = capacity;
    int my_StorageUsed = used;
    bool my_IsPluggedIn = pluggedIn;

}

    FlashDrive operator+(const FlashDrive& flsh1, const FlashDrive& flsh2){


    new1.my_StorageUsed flsh1.my_StorageUsed + flsh2.my_StorageUsed;


    return new1;
}
```

And a main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "flashdrive_2_0.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cs52;

int main( )
{
    cs52::FlashDrive drive1( 10, 0, false );
    cs52::FlashDrive drive2( 20, 0, false );

return 0;
}
```

I want to overload the operator "+" to add the two int values in FlashDrive class. I am getting all kinds of errors in my .cpp file with the definition of the overload operator. I know the constructor takes in three different parameters but I just want to add the int values and disregard the bool. I keep rewriting the

```
FlashDrive operator+(const FlashDrive& flsh1, const FlashDrive& flsh2){}
```

It won't compile. I read material but I still am not understanding how to write the definition to allow me to access the private data in the class. The closest I do get to the definition says that the

```
  FlashDrive operator+(const FlashDrive& flsh1, const FlashDrive& flsh2){

    FlashDrive new1;

    new1.my_StorageUsed = flsh1.my_StorageUsed + flsh2.my_StorageUsed;

    return new1;
}
```

cannot access private member function data for my_StorageUsed?

Comment: In the header, `operator+` is declared to return `FlashDrive`. But in your implementation, you keep trying to have it return `int`. Also, it's not a member of `FlashDrive`, so don't name it `FlashDrive::operator+`

Comment: Okay. I've updated the code to both return type FlashDrive. Still I receive an error about the definition not being able to access private member data my_StorageUsed?

Comment: The friend `operator+` is declared in namespace `cs52`. Are you trying to define it in the global namespace, by any chance? `::operator+` and `cs52::operator+` are two distinct, unrelated functions; only the latter is a `frined`.

Comment: Okay. I think I am trying to define it in local namespace cs52 for the class FlashDrive. I used 

FlashDrive cs52::operator+(const FlashDrive& flsh1, const FlashDrive& flsh2)

it compiled without any errors. Thank you so much Igor I was very stuck.